# SLComposeViewController pick the wrong twitter account

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I login using social framework. I pick the right account.

Then I tried to tweet something

SLComposeViewController default to the first account even though I used the right account.

How can I set SLComposeViewController to use the account I select when I login. There is no account information SLComposeViewController

How's that work?